# What are the spheres that appear over the dragons and what do they do?

Tags: dragonvale

In Dragonvale, when you get a shrine to level up, your dragons can go beyond level ten. When you level them past ten, a sphere shows up over the dragon's head. I'd like to know what they do or what they are.

Comment: Er, Dragon Balls? :P

Answer (score 5):

The spheres are merely there to show (to yourself and your visitors) that your dragons are higher than level ten.

The shrines will show that your dragons are *able* to level past ten (or fifteen if it's gold), but the orbs show for each particular dragon that is above level 10.

Comment: Do it dragons have to be high levels for the spheres to appear?

Comment: @LucySmith Correct. The sphere won't appear until your dragon hits level 11. At level 20, it turns into a crown.

Answer (score -2):

It makes your dragon go faster in races