# What does the sphere on the dragon mean?

Tags: dragonvale

When you bread with another player and you get twin dragons, which means you get one and the fellow breeder gets the same one. They tend to have a sphere above there head and the egg itself glows as well. What does this mean and is it something special?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the spheres that appear over the dragons and what do they do?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/79986/what-are-the-spheres-that-appear-over-the-dragons-and-what-do-they-do)

Comment: No it is different

Comment: Somewhat similar but different the island where the galaxy dragons can breed also you can breed regular dragons and they are born with a spare above there head even as baby's what does it do I mean if it's the same concept then let me know

Comment: You are absolutely right, it is not a duplicate. I retracted my vote to close, and I hope everybody in the review queue reads the comments and decides to keep the question open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just appearance differences. According to the [Dragonvale FAQ](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Twin_Dragons):

> **Appearance Differences**
>
> Twin Dragons appear differently than other dragons.
>
> The most noticeable difference *is a blue orb which hovers above the
>   dragon's head* from levels 1 through level 10.
>
> When the dragon is above level 10 the orb, crown, or star will have a
>   blue glow around it.
>
> The buttons viewable from a habitat has a blue background and a yellow
>   glow border instead of the usual gray stone background.
>
> Likewise, when in the description menu the background will be blue and
>   have a yellow glow border instead of the usual tan dragon scale
>   background.
>
> Twin Dragons eggs have a blue glow over them, and if placed on a
>   pedestal the egg pedestal will also receive a blue glow around the egg
>   on it.

So it is indeed different then the level 10+ sphere (sorry for the confusion), but it seems to be only a difference in appearance.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have this confusion when I started dragon vale too, the sphere hovering over their head just means you've fed the dragon over level 10. you can remove it by clicking on the crown on the bottom right corner when viewing your dragon. hope this helps :)